# How to pass parameters to a redirect route in Request

Tags: laravel, parameters, laravel-5, routes, request

Language is a model binding in route file.

Route

```
Route::post('managment/{Language}/create', ['as' => 'dictionary.store', 'uses' => 'DictionaryController@store' ]);
```

I like to declare a *Request* (DictionaryRequest) file which extends *Request(FormRequest)*, and it's responsible for the request parameter at Controller.

method prototype is :

```
public function store(DictionaryRequest $request, Language $lang)
```

the redirectRoute in the request class is set as :

```
protected $redirectRoute = "dictionary.create";
```

how can I pass on parameter to the route?? (the Langauge model)

I checked FormRequest class, but redirectRoute just passes on to the UrlGenerator with no parameters.

```
/**
 * Get the URL to redirect to on a validation error.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getRedirectUrl()
{
    $url = $this->redirector->getUrlGenerator();

    if ($this->redirect) {
        return $url->to($this->redirect);
    } elseif ($this->redirectRoute) {
        return $url->route($this->redirectRoute);
    } elseif ($this->redirectAction) {
        return $url->action($this->redirectAction);
    }

    return $url->previous();
}
```

Comment: btw I don't want to use  _$url->previous();_ too.

Comment: For what purpose do you need pass whole model instance instead id?

Comment: @huuuk it's doesn't matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try override `getRedirectUrl`?

```
/**
 * Get the URL to redirect to on a validation error.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getRedirectUrl()
{
    $url = $this->redirector->getUrlGenerator();

    return $url->route($this->redirectRoute, [ /*your parameters*/ ]);

}
```